# numpy.allclose() on SciPy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
def simrank_sparse(A,c,maxiter,eps=1e-4):

    if not sp.issparse(A):
        raise Exception("Input is not a sparse matrix ")

    n=sp.csr_matrix.get_shape(A)[0]
    Q=misc.get_column_normalized_matrix(A)
    sim=sp.eye(n)
    I=sp.eye(n)
    sim_prev=sp.csr_matrix(sim)

    for t in range(maxiter):

        if sc.allclose(sim,sim_prev,atol=eps):
            break
        sim_prev=sc.copy(sim)
        sim=c*(Q.T*sim_prev*Q)+(1-c)*I

    print("Converge after %d iterations (eps=%f)." % (t, eps))
    return sim
```

I am using sparse matrices but the `numpy.allclose()` function is giving errors as it only takes numpy arrays as input.  I don't want to convert the sparse matrices to arrays and back to sparse matrices again, as it will be inefficient.  Is there another way to check two sparse matrices for `allclose()`?

Comment: In general, `numpy` functions don't work with `sparse` matrices.  There are exceptions, usually because the function delegates the action to the matrix method.  I don't recall a sparse equivalent, but check the docs.

Comment: To do it from scratch I'd first compare `shape`, `dtype`, and `nnz`.  Then compare the `sim.indptr` attribute.  That's integer, and I think should be `allclose`.  From there we'd have to compare the `.indices` and then the `data` attributes.  But we might need to first check that they are 'cannonical' - all zeros have been removed, duplicates summed, and columns in order.  Lots of things to check.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the architecture for the comparison, and then use numpy for the evaluation:

```
def csr_allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol = 1e-8):
    c = np.abs(np.abs(a - b) - rtol * np.abs(b))
    return c.max() <= atol
```

The `csr_matrix` `c` will contain the difference of the two matrices being compared, and if any of the absolute differences are greater than your threshold levels, `csr_allclose` will return `False`.  This implementation doesn't include the `NaN` features offered by the `numpy.allclose` method, however.

Comment: @Warren: thanks for catching that.  Updated to address error.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the matrices match in sparsity - number of nonzeros and matching nonzero indices, the you could just compare the `data`.

```
np.allclose(sim.data,sim_prev.data,atol=eps)
```

The would be true if the matrices are constructed in the same way, or one is sparsity preserving derivation of the other.

Some time tests:

```
In [153]: M = sparse.random(1000,1000,.2, 'csr')
In [154]: M
Out[154]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Another matrix of same shape, but different sparsity

```
In [155]: M1 = sparse.random(1000,1000,.2, 'csr')
In [156]: 
In [156]: timeit np.abs(M-M1).max()
12.3 ms ± 339 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [157]: timeit np.abs(M.A-M1.A).max()
24.4 ms ± 624 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If the matrices match in sparsity, we can compare the `data` attributes for a considerable time savings:

```
In [158]: M2 = M.copy()
In [159]: M2.data += np.random.rand(M2.data.shape[0])*.001
In [160]: timeit np.abs(M.data-M2.data).max()
2.77 ms ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

A preliminary check on sparsity could save a lot of time (provided we aren't worried `epsilon` size nonzero values):

```
In [170]: timeit np.allclose(M.indptr,M1.indptr)
97.8 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Remove the `toarray()` step from the timings, in effect `allclose` on equivalent size dense arrays:

```
In [164]: %%timeit Ma=M.A; M1a=M1.A
     ...: np.abs(Ma-M1a).max()
     ...: 
14.8 ms ± 31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Subtraction of the sparse matrices is doing better than I expected.

---

Actually I don't need to use `np.abs`; the Python `abs` delegates to `M.__abs__` method, which is:

```
def __abs__(self):
    return self._with_data(abs(self._deduped_data()))
```